# Changing role of two Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, swap

I wrote an iterative MergeSort Function which is working perfectly fine if I call it the following way:

```
void MergeSort(double *a, int n) {
    double *helpArray = new double[n];
    for(int runWidth = 1; runWidth < n; runWidth *= 2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2 * runWidth) {
            Merge(a, helpArray, i, min(i+runWidth, n), min(i+2*runWidth, n));
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            a[j] = helpArray[j];
        }
    }
    delete[] helpArray;
}

int main() {
    int n = 100;
    double *a = 0;
    a = GenerateNumbers(n);
    assert(a != 0);
    MergeSort(a, n);
    cout << "Sorting finished!\n";
    delete[] a;
    exit(0);
}
```

Now in my MergeSort Function I don't always want to copy the `helpArray` back into `a` with the for-loop. I want to change the roles of `a` and `helpArray` but that is giving me a lot of trouble with the deleting and in case of uneven runs of the first for-loop in MergeSort.
I tried the following which is not working:

```
void MergeSort(double *a, int n) {
    double *helpArray = new double[n];
    int count = 0;
    for(int runWidth = 1; runWidth < n; runWidth *= 2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2 * runWidth) {
            Merge(a, helpArray, i, min(i+runWidth, n), min(i+2*runWidth, n));
        }
        swap(a, helpArray);
        count++;
    }
    if(count%2 == 1) {
        swap(a, helpArray);
    }
    delete[] helpArray;
}
```

Of course it is not working :) Maybe someone has a little tip for me how to change the roles of the two Array. Seems like I'm still not deep enough in how Pointers and their referenced Values/Adresses work ...

Greetz

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how it is not working?

Comment: I'm using different sizes for n. For example I use n = 4 (means I have 4 random numbers in my Array a) everything is working and the output seems fine. This is always the case if count%2 == 0. Then everything works. In cases of count%2 == 1 e.g. n = 5 and my Array a would be {0, -1, -2, -3, -4}, after using the MergeSort my output is {-3, -2, -1, 0, -4}. You can see the last one is not the sorted one, it is "wrong" Array.

Comment: Then maybe you should get rid of `if(count%2 == 1) {
        swap(a, helpArray);` ?

Comment: No, then I would delete the wrong Array at the End :) But I got it now, the problem is that swap() is just changing the names of the Pointers, so on uneven runs I had the last "helpArray" at the Adress of a. So I really needed to copy the whole Array back one time, if the first for makes an uneven count of runs. Another way would be to give the Adresses of the Pointers to my functions with (double **a)